# sublime text refuses to start

Tags: sublime-text

I tried installing sublime text 2. Downloaded the i86 for my ubuntu 14.04, untar it, moved to /opt, but it refuses to start. 
This is what I get :

```
sublime

(sublime:4268): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GSimpleAsyncResult'

(sublime:4268): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GAsyncResult'

(sublime:4268): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed

(sublime:4268): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(sublime:4268): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed

(sublime:4268): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(sublime:4268): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are facing this problem, but you could try installing *Sublime Text* the easy way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: Well, I removed the /opt entry, installed like you said, and I have just the same thing.